# Papers about doing development projects by government funding

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, development-economics

I want to read some papers about negative and positive aspects of doing a lot of development projects by government funding from the viewpoint of macroeconomics. However, I can't find anything by searching in google. Can you suggest some papers or a way for finding some papers in this topic?